# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API Swagger UI / Swashbuckle versioning issue route related

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, versioning, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-7.0

I have versioned my Swagger UI successfully in a .NET 7 test project (starting at versions 3/4), but when I applied this methodology to an existing project, I started to get inconsistent behaviour. I accidentally found out that adding another route to the subsequent version (it isn't needed in the default version 3) made the 405 error I was getting go away:

[image]

The aforementioned problem being this 405 error:

[image]

But this has left me with a Swagger UI that looks like this and also asks for the version number as input, which is undesirable to say the least:

[image]

This is the startup of my test project(much easier to copy/paste):

[image]

Comment: I just found out that adding an Swagger IDocument Filter achieves the desired end result, but still i am not that keen on adding a route just to make this work

Comment: Have you tried this in postman or something?

Comment: Yes, both swagger ui and postman behave the same when making API calls, if i do not have that route i get that 405 error.  I use a filter to remove the route from swagger.  This is some retrofit issue, as a it didnt happen on a clean new solution i made

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77532933/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally worked out what was wrong with this.

I was using a deprecated [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package: *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Versioning.Mvc*

I should have been using: *Asp.Versioning.Mvc*